# Epson ink levels above 100% using ink

Tags: 14.04, printing, epson

I am using an EPSON Stylus DX4050 printer on my Ubuntu machine, and since I upgraded to 14.04, my ink level tools are giving incoherent results:

```
$ sudo ink -p usb 
ink 0.5.1 (c) 2010 Markus Heinz

EPSON Stylus DX4000

Cyan:                         114%
Yellow:                       105%
Magenta:                      105%
Photoblack:                   105%
```

According to my printer, one of my ink tanks is empty. For this reason, the printer won't print anything. I thought it was black, but nothing changed after I replaced it.

Before the upgrade to 14.04, the `ink` utility gave proper results. I also tried using `mtink` and `escputil`, however:

- `mtink` does not list my EPSON model, and does not pick any level when selecting *Other printer*.
- `escputil` keeps running without outputting anything.

Earlier today, `ink` returned correct results (which revealed that the missing color was yellow, not black), but I could not manage to make this happen again, even by restarting the printer, or using a different USB port. Is there any way to fix this and get access to my actual ink levels?